# Append the bytes of a uint32 to a byte slice?

Tags: go, binary, byte, slice, endianness

If I have an existing `[]byte`, what is the recommended way to append the bytes of one or more `uint32` value(s) to it?

For example, what should I replace `// ???` with:

```
s := []byte{0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03}

u := uint32(0x07060504)
// ???

fmt.Println(s)  // Should print [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
```

**Edit:** One option would be `s = append(s, byte(u)); s = append(s, byte(u >> 8)); s = append(s, byte(u >> 16)); s = append(s, byte(u >> 24))`, but is there a more idiomatic way to do this? Perhaps using [package binary](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) and/or [package bytes](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/)?

Answer (score 3):

One option is to append the individual bytes as suggested in the question.  The multiple `append` calls can be combined into a single call:

```
s = append(s, byte(u), byte(u>>8), byte(u>>16), byte(u>>24))
```

The binary package can also be used as the question suggests:

```
var b [4]byte
binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(b[:], u)
s = append(s, b[:]...)
```

[Run it on the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/LM-DynBi0HC).

The last snippet should allocate `b` on the stack. If it does not, then the extra heap allocation can be avoided with the following code:

```
s = append(s, "    "...) // append four bytes (the values don't matter)
binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(s[len(s)-4:], u) // overwrite those bytes with the uint32
```

Answer (score 1):

encoding/binary has the functions you need:

```
import "encoding/binary"

b := make([]byte,4)
binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(b, u)
s = append(s, b)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a function to do it without the need to create a temporary slice?

Comment: Not that I know. You can create the initial slice larger, if that's an option: `s:=[]byte{0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0} binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(s[3:],u)`

Answer (score -3):

There's unsafe (actually safe, if you will only copy its bytes) way to get byte representation of any primitive:

```golang
const sizeUInt32 = int(unsafe.Sizeof(uint32(0)))

func GetBytesUInt32(i *uint32) []byte {
   return (*[1 << 30]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(i))[:sizeUInt32:sizeUInt32]
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/WPC5jeYLDth

Created slice will carry passed int's storage, so by making a manipulations with it keep in mind that uint32 value will be changed too.

---

Hey, what a hate without discussion? I realize that you guys don't like unsafe code, and I realize that such answer isn't `recommended way` for which topic starter looking... but I think that such place as stackoverflow should offer all of possibles ways to implement thing people googling for.